# How could I control the permissions for particular set of jenkins jobs, while proving build permission to whole organization

Tags: jenkins

Thanks for looking into my concern.

I want to give build permissions to whole organization in Jenkins. And, at the same time I want to control the release jobs.

How could I do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin) to set permissions for individual jobs.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I am using this plugin already. But, I want to control on view level, instead of doing for every job. something like role-based.

Comment: If I'm understanding your comment correctly, then the only solution like that I've seen before is combining Matrix Auth with the Cloudbees commercial folder plugin, which (unlikely the "normal" folders) allow you to set permissions at the folder level. I am not affiliated with Cloudbees, nor do I endorse this solution, but it seems to fit your needs. If I really can't trust people to keep their hands off the production deployments, I'll segregate by having two instances of Jenkins, one with permission to deploy on dev and another with access to the prod servers. The job configs are the same.

Answer (score 0):

this plugin should be of help - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ownership+Plugin